# How to use router connect via cable like a wifi card in Kali Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking

I'm doing a Kali Linux course and next concepts are about airmon and airodump.

The practice requires that you install a Oracle Extension to active USB 2.0(EHCI) device and select your wifi cardboard.

The problem I dont have wifi cardboard.

I have this ethernet card: Atheros ar8151 pci-e gigabit ethernet controller (ndis 6.20)

And this router connected via LAN cable: ZXHN H108L

Is posible to set that modem like a wifi cardboard to active wlan and capture air traffic?

I tried using Tethering with my phone (android 6.0), and the extension recognize the `BLU ADVANCE[FFFF]` like a `usb2.0 EHCI` element.

But when I run the VMs with kali linux my host pc lost the internet connection (apparently is normal).

The kali linux DONT GET INTERNET.

**Update 15-08-2017**

I Triyed this for get internet:

*1* Go to network configuracion of the VM and set the brige adapter and select `remote NDIS Based Internet Shared Device`

*2* Go to VM run the machine (the cellphone get disconected for HOST)

*3* Later do this:

Unplug the phone, replug phone.

*4* Internet works in KALI LINUX

> *The problem* Only appear usb0 non like a wlan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the answer is no, you cannot do that. The sorts of information you'd get in a wireless frame won't make it onto the ethernet connection. For example, there are no beacon frames in ethernet.

You can, however, use a wifi router + ethernet to get onto a wifi network, just not to sniff wireless packets (AFAIK).

Comment: and someway to virtualize a wifi?

Answer (score 1):

**Truth is you can’t use host machine wifi adapter in virtualbox.**

Yes you read that right you can’t use host pc/laptop build in wifi adapter in virtualbox and the above statement is absolutely true and i have spent many hours figuring out how to enable it and reason i found on web is:-

“VirtualBox or any virtualization application abstract the hardware of its host machine, and creates the virtual or hypervisor layer between the host machine’s hardware and virtual or hypervisor application”

Pretty simple huh? In layman terms it means that to use host pc hardware virtualisation software builds a virtual layer between the hardware on host pc and virtual application due to which we are unable to access wifi adapter.

To counter this problem there are mainly two way:-

**Dual boot**:-This is a method in which you don’t have to spend a single penny.Dual boot simply means to install multiple operating system on single machine and you will find tons of tutorials on youtube.

**External wifi adapter**:-This is somewhat easy method but you have to spend some money to buy a decent wifi adapter from amazon or flipkart.Once you have bought one just connect it and navigate to Devices—>USB and you will find the external wifi adapter.
So these are only two methods to use wifi adapter of host machine on virtualisation software.If you know another one let me know in comment section.